# What's the definition of "rate of uniform convergence"?

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, rate-of-convergence

What's the definition of "**rate of uniform convergence**"?

I'm reading "[Understanding Machine Learning: From theory to algorithms](https://www.cse.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf)". You can click the hyperlink to download the book.

I came across this phrase in the **preface of Chapter 26: Rademacher Complexities, Page 375**.
I have looked up a lot of materials, but I didn't get the definition of "**rate of uniform convergence**". Hope you can help me!

Comment: In what context did you see this phrase?

Comment: @kimchilover I have added the context to the question.